# Dynamics ax 2012 AIF date not accepting

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

Keep receiving exception message like this "Error reading value of type Date from XML." While inserting the salesorder using aif.

```html
   //string deliverdt = "19/05/2017";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(deliverdt, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

AxdEntity_SalesTable salesTable = new AxdEntity_SalesTable();
salesTable.CurrencyCode = "USD";
salesTable.CustAccount = "C-000003";
salesTable.DeliveryDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 19); // Convert.ToDateTime("19/05/2017"); //System.DateTime.Now; 
// salesTable.DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
//Convert.ToDateTime("5/19/2017");
salesTable.Payment = "N07";
salesTable.PurchOrderFormNum = "PO";

AxdEntity_SalesLine salesLine = new AxdEntity_SalesLine();
salesLine.ItemId = "A3300-HV";
salesLine.SalesQty = 1;
salesLine.SalesUnit = "ea";
salesLine.SalesPrice = 2000;
```

Comment: According to a duplicate question on another forum ([link](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/237744)), this particular problem "disappeared".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `salesTable.DeliveryDateSpecified = true;`?

.NET wrapper creates *Specified* properties for value types.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to fulfill field `salesTable.ReceiptDateRequested`